# Changing argv[0] with winapi

Tags: winapi, argv

My goal is to change the path the application restarts from. I don't have access to `main`, but I am free to run C code via ctypes.

I was able to change argv[0] in Solarios with `getexecname()`, that gave me a pointer to it, to which I did `memcpy`.

I was wondering if there is a method in winapi that allows me to either find `argv[0]` pointer, or an API function that changed it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston this is for Firefox. After addon install or other things, Firefox can be restarted. Im not exctly sure how it restarts, but I was told to use ctypes to change the argv.

Comment: Looks like this is how it restarts, its open source: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/startup/nsAppStartup.cpp#466

Comment: Found it @Harry! http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/startup/nsAppStartup.cpp#301 is called from here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/startup/nsAppStartup.cpp#984 does that make sense haha? The person who told me to change argv[0] is pretty smart guy who works for Firefox so im pretty sure if i can change it will work

Comment: The `argv[]` array passed to `main()` comes from the C runtime library.  So how this is implemented depends on which compiler Mozilla use.  Assuming Visual Studio, I believe there is a global `char ** __argv` (defined in stdlib.h) which you should be able to modify.  (Of course this assumes that Firefox doesn't make its own copy.)

Comment: Thanks @Harry! Ill look into that :) If you know of an example that would be awesome :D My biggest struggle is finding the address to that global `__argv`

Comment: You can get the address of an exported variable using GetProcAddress().  Looking at the CRT source, the exported variable might either be `__p___argv` (a pointer to `__argv`) or `__argv` itself, depending on the platform.  (Or perhaps something completely different, if Mozilla don't use Visual Studio 2010, or if I'm reading the source incorrectly.)  You'll need to work out which CRT DLL Firefox is importing anyway in order to call GetModuleHandle(), Process Explorer can tell you that.

Comment: What sort of voodoo are you going to implement to make sure that the memory `argv[0]` points to is sufficiently sized to hold its designated new content?

Comment: Hahaha @IInspectable ok ill look for another solution

Comment: @IInspectable: since argv[] is an array of pointers, what's wrong with writing a new pointer to argv[0]?  (I mean, apart from presumably being at least a technical violation of the language standard?)

Comment: @Harry: Since you don't know which allocator was used to allocate argv[0] you cannot dispose of the previous value, and you cannot transfer ownership of a newly allocated memory resource, without risking to raise havoc. argv[0] belongs to someone else. It's not yours to tamper with.

Comment: @IInspectable: but why would you even *try* to dispose of the previous value?  And unless the CRT frees argv[] on exit, which is unlikely, there's no risk there either.  Even if it does (and I admit I didn't check) we've got the source code so we can determine which allocator is appropriate.  I'm not saying messing with argv[] is a good idea, mind you, but memory safety per se does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: @Harry: I agree that cleaning up memory is not strictly required here. However, the fact that you (presumably) can read the CRT source code does not imply that you have immediate access to its implementation. The specific allocator could use a private heap (created with [HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599.aspx)), for example. Plus, the `argv` array could be in read-only memory. Someone willing to invest a lot can probably work around these issues as well. It's just a lot more complex than it initially appeared.

Comment: @IInspectable: to be more precise, it *might* be more complex.  Odds are that it isn't.  The CRT would have to go out of its way to use a different heap just for argv[], to release it on exit, or to set read-only permissions on the memory.  Microsoft *probably* wouldn't have done that without a reason. :-)

Answer (score 2):

on Windows, your command line is in the PEB (Process Environment Block). You probably should not modify it, but you can find it and act upon it.

you can find it using GetCommandLine(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx

and parse it either yourself, or using CommandLineToArgvW https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx -- then launch a new instance of yourself (using CreateProcess or ShellExecute, whatever is applicable), and terminate. New instance of you will have the right params.